# See if Input Has Spaces with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function that reads a inputs value, and determines if a space has been used in it's creation. I'm not trying to trim anything -- just see if it would have needed the ability to trim.

I'm not even sure where to begin on this, so I don't have any code to look at. Please help if you can!

I was trying this solution but it doesn't seem to work (I don't think I'm using .has() correctly)

```
if ($('#id').val().has(" ")) {
            alert('has spaces')
        }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) :

```
var hasSpace = $('#myInputId').val().indexOf(' ')>=0;
```

If you want to test other types of "spaces" (for example a tabulation), you might use a regex :

```
var hasSpace = /\s/g.test($('#myInputId').val());
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/MzfLF/)

Comment: I would use `indexOf(' ') > -1` :-)

Comment: And I would use `.match(/\s/g)`... oh, your update beat me to it.

Comment: @codingbiz Why would `>-1` be better than `>=0` ?

Comment: `!!~( '' + $('#myInputId').val() ).indexOf(' ')` The `!!~` will force the result indexOf to boolean. You should make sure that the result is a string b/c `.val()` can also return null|undefined|number.

Comment: when a character is not found, -1 is returned, so it's default to test for -1. but that's just one way to achieve the same result

Comment: @ryanve OK. I hadn't read the updated comment when answering it. I was in the process of testing the "fancy" way in a fiddle and I concluded this was too much complexity just to be hype...

Comment: @dystroy LOL It's all hype ;]

Answer (score 0):

Use contains for include space:

```
var value = $('#myInputId').val();
if(value.contains(' ')){
   console.log("has space");
}
```

Or you can find with these ascII code &nbsp and \xA0

```
if(value.contains('&nbsp;')){
   console.log("has space");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use val and space:

```
$('#name').val().length <= 0 || $('#name').val(" ")
```