# no spaces allowed in username input code screwy

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See if Input Has Spaces with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257007/see-if-input-has-spaces-with-jquery)

I have this code for no spaces. Well atleast I thought it was for no spaces in username in registration...Now looking at it it is for every single key up! Can someone help me to make it spaces only?

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
        $('#username_reg').keyup(function(){
            str = $(this).val(),
            str = str.replace(/\s/g,''),
            $(this).val(str),
            alert('No space are allowed in usernames');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I tried this code as well just now, did not work :/

```
$("input#username_reg").on("keydown", function (e) {
    return e.which !== 32;
 });​
```

Comment: You, my friend, are in need of some regex awesomeness...

Comment: Proper formatting makes it easier for others to help you. FYI, you can omit the outer function expression and just do `jQuery(function($) { ...});`. And why do you have commas at the end of each line?

Comment: formatting? Sorry if you are talking about indentations, I really do not know whats the difference between indents beside "tidyness". And I don't use regex. Yes its in the code above, but a mate helped me with the code a while back.

Comment: The callback function receives an `event` as an argument, so you can check `event.keyCode` to see if it's a space.

Comment: @Barmar how exactly? str=$(this)event.keyCode()???

Comment: Just as a side note... remember to validate your input server-side as well.

Comment: Do you know what "function argument" means?

Comment: Like I said, a mate helped with the code before. function argument? I only have been jQuery/javascript for 4months mate.

Comment: _'And I don't use regex.'_ - Yes you do, that's what the `/\s/g` bit in your code is. _'I really do not know whats the difference between indents beside "tidyness".'_ - The difference is that the indenting makes it clear which lines of code are grouped within which function, making it _much_ easier for us to read and understand your code and therefore _much_ easier for us to help you. (Thewayyouhaditisthecodingequivalentofdoingsomethinglikethis.)

Comment: gotcha...and not a duplicate...??? I just want this code to work correctly. I had a code before I dont remember where it is or whatever but it had the event.keyCode == 32 or somehting like that for spaces. It did not work, it spaced with an alert I don't want a space at all.

Comment: lol love it 
(Thewayyouhaditisthecodingequivalentofdoingsomethinglikethis.) 
I will try and get better at the indentation for you nnnnnn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the following code will do what you want:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#username_reg').keyup(function(e){
        if (e.which === 32) {
            alert('No space are allowed in usernames');
            var str = $(this).val();
            str = str.replace(/\s/g,'');
            $(this).val(str);            
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        var str = $(this).val();
        str = str.replace(/\s/g,'');
        $(this).val(str);            
    });
});
```

That is, on keyup, if the key was a space display the alert with the message and remove the space. But also, on blur remove any spaces that might be in the field - because the user may copy/paste or drag'n'drop without using the keyboard.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wP8mP/

EDIT: If it were my code I would probably remove the alert altogether - I'd just prevent spaces being typing by calling `event.preventDefault()` on key *down,* and still remove spaces on blur in case of a copy/paste.

```
$('#username_reg').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.which === 32) {
        e.preventDefault();      
    }
}).blur(function() {
    // for variety's sake here's another way to remove the spaces:
    $(this).val(function(i,oldVal){ return oldVal.replace(/\s/g,''); });         
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wP8mP/1/

Comment: That code did not seem to work for an odd reason. By any chance is this no cross browser compatible? Please don't hate me for asking :/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the `e` argument in the function declaration so that was giving an error. Fixed, and demo provided.

Comment: Thank you very much nnnnnn you saved me! Though I will not lie, it looks jibberish to me, i'm no expert at coding. Clearly. Thank you though alot!